# friggeri-cv aside flow to next page

Tags: friggeri-cv

I was trying use the FrigeriCV template to create a CV. I am using this https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/smart-fancy-cv template .
When the experience flows to next page the contents in the \aside not flowing to next page. How can I fix that?
The same TEX code is available at https://gist.github.com/jaganadhg/4c37fcf2d2321c418442aa0b37ebf6ee

Comment: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25780 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180469/pagebreak-in-left-column-friggeri-cv-theres-no-line-here-to-end

Comment: If you want a more concrete answer from the community, do consider providing a working Minimal working example (MWE) beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Troy Here is a sample code https://gist.github.com/jaganadhg/4c37fcf2d2321c418442aa0b37ebf6ee . If compile the same you can see that the aisle in page 1 is not flowing to page to. It is getting truncated.